# Spark job not showing up on standalone cluster GUI

Tags: apache-spark

I am playing with running spark jobs in my lab and have a three node standalone cluster.  When I execute a new job on the master node via CLI
`spark-submit sparktest.py --master spark://myip:7077`
while the job completes as expected it does not show up at all on the cluster GIU.  After some investigation, I added the --master to the submit command but to no avail.  During job execution as well as after completion when I navigate to `http://mymasternodeip:8080/`
none of these jobs are recognized in Running Jobs nor Completed Jobs.  Any thoughts as to why the jobs dont show up would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify --master flag first then remaining flags/options. If not master will be considered as local.

```
spark-submit --master spark://myip:7077 sparktest.py
```

Make sure that you don't override master config in your code while creating SparkSession object. Provide same master url in code also or don't add it.